# How to check if text fields are empty on form submit using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, form-submit

How could I use jQuery to check if text-fields are empty when submitting without loading `login.php`?

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <label>Login Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="log" />
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="pwd" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use required attribute. As a fallback for compatibility you can use other ways.

Comment: @NEO "other ways" offers no help at all.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event using jQuery [`.submit`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) method and then get trimmed `#log` text field value and check if empty of not like:

```
$('form').submit(function () {

    // Get the Login Name value and trim it
    var name = $.trim($('#log').val());

    // Check if empty of not
    if (name  === '') {
        alert('Text-field is empty.');
        return false;
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LHZXw/1/)

Comment: This doesn't work for firfox browser, can you provide which will for chrome and firefox browser.

Answer (score 12):

You can use 'required' http://jsbin.com/atefuq/1/edit

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <label>Login Name:</label>
    <input required type="text" name="email" id="log" />
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input required type="password" name="password" id="pwd" />
    <input  required type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does required still not work on the Safari browser?  This is what is said today on w3schools.

Answer (score 11):

A simple solution would be something like this

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function() { 

   var has_empty = false;

   $(this).find( 'input[type!="hidden"]' ).each(function () {

      if ( ! $(this).val() ) { has_empty = true; return false; }
   });

   if ( has_empty ) { return false; }
});
```

Note: The [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method is only available in jQuery version 1.7+, but it is now the preferred method of attaching event handlers.

This code loops through all of the inputs in the form and prevents form submission by returning false if any of them have no value. Note that it doesn't display any kind of message to the user about why the form failed to submit (I would strongly recommend adding one).

Or, you could look at the [jQuery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin. It does this and a lot more.

NB: This type of technique should always be used in conjunction with server side validation.

Comment: But this will check for hidden fields as well and if they are empty it will prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Good point. I added an attribute selector to ignore hidden fields.

Comment: Won't this just set `has_empty` according to the value of the last input on the form?

Comment: Not really. We initialize `has_empty` to `false` and then loop through each input in the form. If any input is empty, we set `has_empty` to `true` _and_ break the loop (that's what the `return false` is about). Then we simply check the value of `has_empty` and conditionally return `false` to prevent form submission if there are empty fields.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add a handler to the form [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event. In the handler you need to check for each text field, select element and password fields if there values are non empty.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
     var res = true;
     // here I am checking for textFields, password fields, and any 
     // drop down you may have in the form
     $("input[type='text'],select,input[type='password']",this).each(function() {
         if($(this).val().trim() == "") {
             res = false; 
         }
     })
     return res; // returning false will prevent the form from submitting.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I really hate forms which don't tell me what input(s) is/are missing.
So I improve the Dominic's answer - thanks for this.

In the css file set the "borderR" class to border has red color.

```
$('#<form_id>').submit(function () {
    var allIsOk = true;

    // Check if empty of not
    $(this).find( 'input[type!="hidden"]' ).each(function () {
        if ( ! $(this).val() ) { 
            $(this).addClass('borderR').focus();
            allIsOk = false;
        }
    });

    return allIsOk
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you should try with jquery validate plugin :

```
$('form').validate({
   rules:{
       email:{
          required:true,
          email:true
       }
   },
   messages:{
       email:{
          required:"Email is required",
          email:"Please type a valid email"
        }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isEmpty(val) {
if(val.length ==0 || val.length ==null){
    return 'emptyForm';
}else{
    return 'not emptyForm';
}
```

}

```
$(document).ready(function(){enter code here
    $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        $('input').each(function(){
           var getInputVal = $(this).val();
            if(isEmpty(getInputVal) =='emptyForm'){
                alert(isEmpty(getInputVal));
            }else{
                alert(isEmpty(getInputVal));
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code might solve the OPs problem, can you please explain why and how it does this? This would greatly improve the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var save_val = $("form").serializeArray();
$(save_val).each(function( index, element ) {
    alert(element.name);
    alert(element.val);
});
```