# Put a jquery-function before form-send?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, send

I have a form. 
I need to implement a jquery-file-upload before the form is beeing sent.

How can I capture if the send-button has been clicked, to display and preform a file-upload, and finaly send the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery form submit to check empty fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556968/jquery-form-submit-to-check-empty-fields)

Comment: I dont need a validation, but to put a file-upload-plugin betweeen user-click-on-submit .. and .. form beein submitted

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.submit()`

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  //event.preventDefault();
  return true;
});
```

submit() will trigger before html submit and will finish processing and then hand over to html submit if it returns true otherwise if returns false it stops the submit.

Comment: and then use `return true` to finally submit the form

Comment: @lanis ... Thanks :)

Comment: To elaboriate on @lanis's comment - `return true` proceeds with the submission while `return false` will stop it. Using the `event` object is unnecessary.